# Ubuntu: Python version, virtualenvwrapper and django

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

i have a problem with virtualenvs and django. Apparently i just dont get how they are supposed to work.

I installed python 2.7.3 ucs2 in /opt/bin/python and it works just fine
I installed virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper and created virtual environment named py273ucs2 so when i type workon py273ucs2 i get correct virtual environment.

when i create python script with

```
#!/home/alan/python/virtualenvs/py273ucs2/bin/python

import sys
print sys.maxunicode
```

i get 65535 which is correct for ucs2 python.

at same time i have no idea how to use correct virtualenvironment for my django app so i could use ucs2 python not ucs4 one. I tried creating one test project with virtualenvwrapper.django thinking that its wsgi file or manage.py would give me hints about how to start wsgi script with correct environment - no such luck.

I found this site:
http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2009/05/notes-using-pip-and-virtualenv-django/

which basically (in addition to other things that i already did) tells me to add this into my wsgi file :

```
site.addsitedir('/srv/python-environments/saltycrane/lib/python2.5/site-packages')
```

which in my case is:

```
site.addsitedir('/home/alan/python/virtualenvs/py273ucs2/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
```

Tried - no luck.
Then there is such page:
http://www.gyford.com/phil/writing/2011/06/27/virtualenv-webfaction.php
In addition to last page it suggests i add:

```
activate_this = os.path.expanduser("~/.virtualenvs/my_env_name/bin/activate_this.py")
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
```

which in my case is:

```
activate_this = os.path.expanduser("/home/alan/python/virtualenvs/py273ucs2/bin/activate_this.py")
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
```

again no luck.. view

```
def base(request):
    return HttpResponse(sys.version+' maxunicode ' +str(sys.maxunicode))
```

prints out python version 2.7.2 and maxunicode 1114111 not 65535.

Then there is this message here at stackoverflow:
[How does django work with virtualenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11111434/how-does-django-work-with-virtualenv)
which suggests i add params in httd.conf - also tried and also not working.

So honestly - im not getting this. Perhaps the version is supposed to remain 2.7.2 not become 2.7.3... then whats the point of virtualenvs... Or im doing something wrong and not getting something from those examples. I also checked wsgi wiki about virtualevns:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/VirtualEnvironments

and modified my httpd.conf to:

```
WSGIPythonHome /home/alan/python/virtualenvs/py273ucs2
WSGIPythonPath /home/alan/python/virtualenvs/py273ucs2/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIDaemonProcess printer user=alan group=alan processes=5 threads=5 python-path=/home/alan/python/virtualenvs/py273ucs2/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup printer
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/alan/projects/printer/printer.wsgi
```

Nothing. Still see python 2.7.2 in view...

could someone help me out please :)

Alan

Edit1: answer to comments:

1)
I have to install/compile new mod_wsgi if i want to use virtualenvironment? why?

2)
if i do:

```
alan@alan:~$ workon py273ucs2
(py273ucs2)alan@alan:~$ cd projects/printer/
(py273ucs2)alan@alan:~/projects/printer$ python manage.py runserver
Validating models...

0 errors found
Django version 1.3, using settings 'printer.settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[08/Jul/2012 05:01:00] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 68
```

then my view shows me:

2.7.3 (default, May 16 2012, 10:58:59) [GCC 4.6.1] maxunicode 65535

Edit2: Thanks to the help of Graham Dumpleton at modwsgi google group i managed to install mod_wsgi for ucs2 python (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/modwsgi/F5Wn4uWrQAg).

But when i start this site i still get

2.7.2+ (default, Oct 4 2011, 20:41:12) [GCC 4.6.1] maxunicode 1114111

not

2.7.3 (default, Jul 9 2012, 13:32:29) [GCC 4.6.1] maxunicode 65535

Btw apache error log prints out this:

[Mon Jul 09 14:13:19 2012] [warn] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.3.
[Mon Jul 09 14:13:19 2012] [warn] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.2+.

Final edit:

There were several problems with how the mod_wsgi was supposed to be installed. You can find out all necessary info when you follow this link : https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/modwsgi/F5Wn4uWrQAg.

But after those problems the point was that the way Ubuntu python installation is made it conflicts with other pythons (not the best explanation probably but you will find very good explanation by Graham Dumpleton if you follow the link above). Virtual python and mod_wsgi started all working when i removed libapache2-mod-python package. It caused other problems, but those problems are caused by the way ubuntu and its python package are set up.

So if you are ubuntu user and happen to find same problem, then this page and Graham Dupmpletons Huge efforts will probably help you too.

Comment: Did you forget to compile mod_wsgi against the version you want?

Comment: if you are running django from command line after activating your virtualenv. Does it work as expected?

Comment: then your problem is more with mod_wsgi than anything else. because your venv works from command line. http://technomilk.wordpress.com/2011/08/10/running-our-django-site-with-mod_wsgi-and-virtualenv-part-2/ try that

Comment: thanks. didnt work though. More info in edit2.

Comment: WSGIPythonHome /home/alan/.virtualenvs/py273ucs2 ?

Comment: WSGIPythonPath /home/alan/.virtualenv/py273ucs2/lib/python.../site-packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate of:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/modwsgi/F5Wn4uWrQAg

Issue documented at:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationIssues#Mixing_32_Bit_And_64_Bit_Packages

Use '--enable-shared' when configuring/installing Python.

Comment: thanks for all your help dude :). ITs not duplicate of the first link, because HERE i asked how to get virtualenv working with django and there i asked how to install mod_wsgi for correct python version.

Answer (score 0):

You can't install a virtualenv of a python version you don't have already installed.

The point of virtualenv is to isolate your packages. If you create a virtualenv with `--no-site-packages`. It won't use the packages already installed on the system. In other words, it means you can install multiple version of each package for one pythone binary.

Having virtualenv also make it easier for development since you don't require root access to install packages using `python setup.py` or `pip install`.

It's not really clear from what you're posting, why it isn't working.

to activate a virtualenv. You have to do

```
source path/to/env/bin/activate
```

When running scripts from config, pointing out where python is located should be enough. If you do add_site_package, it is probably only adding to the python by default and not the one you wanted.

If nothing works, you might be able to do that. It should solve your problem if nothing requires the other python executable.

using `which python`, you should be able to know where is located the current python executable.

You could replace the symlink for the default python to your python2.7.3ucs. But I can't promise it's not going to break something somewhere. Since some programs may depend on that particular python2.7.2

**edit**

Apparently, your problem is definitely not with virtualenv. But with mod_wsgi. Here is a site that describe how to compile mod_wsgi for your desired python version.

http://technomilk.wordpress.com/2011/08/10/running-our-django-site-with-mod_wsgi-and-virtualenv-part-2/

this line:

```
$ ./configure --with-python=/home/isigma/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.2/bin/python
```

This is where you put the path to your python version and then follow the steps. And hopefully it will work like butter.

**edit 2**

If nothing else work, it might mean you have to check for alternatives to mod_wsgi.

Here is a good one.

http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/Example

**edit 3**

Create a new virtualenv like that

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages --python=/opt/bin/python
```

Comment: i have that python version installed. I installed it ages ago.

Comment: Tried that. downloaded modwsgi and tried installing it for this ucs2 python version. Got some error related to unicodecharacters which i have no idea how to fix. /opt/lib/libpython2.7.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=65536
.
make: *** [mod_wsgi.la] Error 1

Comment: /opt/lib/libpython2.7.a is sure the libpython of your 2.7.3?

Comment: Btw, if you don't require wsgi, you can run it as a forward proxy. you might want to check uWSGI and other method. mod_wsgi might be impossible but other methods might work. uWSGI will create a socket to transfer data. In other words your app will listen to a file and apache or nginx will write there. So there is no real need for compiling anything else

Comment: Ok. I installed modwsgi. There was This awesome dude Graham who helped me to do that at modwsgi google groups (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/modwsgi/F5Wn4uWrQAg). My mod_wsgi version is 3.3 now - no idea what it was before, but 3.3 is also the version i compiled right now. So either this new version of mod_wsgi is working for both virtualenv and not. Or its not working for virtualenv. In any case - my test page still shows wrong python version.

Comment: Since your problem with python seem to be resolved. try to create a new virtualenv with the new binary

Comment: Did that. Removed all virtualenvs. Even reinstalled both virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper. Both still work fine after reinstallation, but do not give desired effect.

Comment: yes.. and by they way:alan@alan:/usr/lib/apache2/modules$ mkvirtualenv --no-site-packages --python=/opt/bin/python py273ucs2
Running virtualenv with interpreter /opt/bin/python
The --no-site-packages flag is deprecated; it is now the default behavior.

Comment: did you update WSGIPythonHome to your new virtualenv? because everything seems right